# Sending data from PHP

Tags: php, send

I need to 'export' certain information with PHP. However, sending an email won't solve my issue. I also don't want to use PECL functions since the package is not installed by default and I can't know whether it is on the server I'll need to send the information from.

Considering I'm dragging the information from a certain file with a regular expression or whatever and sending it out to an external source. The best scenario would be to write the information to a remote file so that it is publicly easily accessible. I thought of forging a raw socket and appending the data to an additional header but I don't know how that could work. Again, as I said, `mail()` isn't an alternative in this case.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "export"? Please be less cryptic.

Comment: First, this sounds fishy.  Set up an FTP server remotely and then use FTP functions.  Set up a remote webserver and use cURL to post it to the remote site.  Set up sockets and send the data.

Comment: That's what I meant. I cannot make my mind how to do it with a socket. And by 'export' I mean 'send'.

Comment: What do you need to send, and where or whom to? You're being so cryptic that we could as well tell you to print your information on paper, attach it to the leg of a pidgeon and let your feathered buddy fly.

Comment: Simple one line text. I need to save it to a file which would be publically accessible by anyone. Could be a script that makes a pastebin.com record and returns the link to the paste.

Comment: Make script on the other end that takes the data either as GET if you're sending 1 small line or as POST if you want to send entire file, then you can use cURL to send the data out or attach the file(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have little data, you could use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) method and append your data URL encoded as parameter to a web resource. The receiver could be a simple PHP script as well.

**sender.php**

```
$data_plain = "to be sent";
$data_enc   = urlencode($data);
file_get_contents("https://www.your-receiver.com/receiver.php?data=" . $data_enc);
```

**receiver.php**

```
$data_enc   = $_GET["data"];
$data_plain = urldecode($data_enc);
```

Comment: You mean file_put_contents instead of file_get_contents? and $_GET("data"); $_GET[''];

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it in a variable (and have server side processing done at the same time)

```
$file = 'some_file.php';
ob_start();
include_once($file);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $contents;
```

Comment: Excuse me but how is this related to the question?

Comment: It's an alternative to what Luke Braune put with `file_get_contents()`. It allows you to fetch certain information, and manipulate it. "Considering I'm dragging the information from a certain file" - Above gets information from a certain file; therefore, relevant.

Comment: Yes but my issue is not related to getting the information but sending it out.

Comment: You could work around this issue the other way around. For example, you could setup some sort of script to encode the information in JSON format, and use cURL, or `file_get_contents()` on the other line to fetch it, and then decode it.